# Why are you rejecting this Edit - Changed

Tags: discussion, edits

I seem to recall that the options for rejecting an edit included "Too minor" or something similar. Just wondering about the reasoning behind taking that option off?

Current options show as:
[image]

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238333/what-guidance-should-be-given-when-edits-are-rejected/238340#comment781154_238336

Comment: This question at meta as well, discusses (announces?) that the "too minor" reasoning is going away: [Approve as too minor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor)

Comment: I thought there would be something announcing it, just couldn't type it correctly to find it I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are at least two questions where this change has been suggested/discussed:

- [Approve as too minor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor). An old question where @Shog in 13th of August makes many suggestions, one of them being:

  > 3. Get rid of the "too minor" reject reason entirely.
- @Shog's question (20th of August): [What guidance should be given when edits are rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238333/what-guidance-should-be-given-when-edits-are-rejected), where he starts with:

  > I'm hoping to get rid of the "too minor" edit rejection reason, in favor of...

  and where @Gilles' answer has among other things:

  > We're getting a better mechanism for too minor, good riddance.

Finally, although I don' think there is a public announcement yet, except for the discussions and comments linked above, the ***"unofficial list of new features and various changes to Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network"***
, maintained by the users, in the meta question:
[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), has:

> **September 2014**
>
> 2014-09-10: Suggested edit review offers a new button “Improve Edit” instead of “Improve”. This action will fail any known-bad
>   audits, while "Reject and Edit" action will pass these audits.
>
> 2014-09-09: Numbered list can now start with any number, not just 1.
>
> ***2014-09-08: "Too minor" was removed from the suggested edits reject reasons list.***
>
> 2014-09-05: Suggested edit review offers a new button “Reject and Edit”.